# C++ Class with templated and non-templated form

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am curious if it is possible to have a class with both a templated and non-templated form. Something like:

```
SomeClass foo;
SomeClass<int> bar;

foo.do_something();
bar.do_something(5);
```

I am fine defining everything more than once, but I don't know if it's possible to use the same class name.

Comment: I'm actually not sure. I'd say no, but you can of course use default template parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no, it's not allowed. The exact error message your compiler gives you will vary, but you should get an error message.

You can, however, provide default parameters for a template, so you can instantiate it with only `<>`, like:

```
template <class T=int>
class X {};

int main(){ 
    X<long> a;
    X<>     b; // used default, so equivalent to "X<int> b;"
}
```

Comment: And the reason for that is the compiler has no idea what code to generate. The type argument is not there for pretty decoration but in order to give the compiler enough information to figure out things like the size of the objects to allocate, when you call the constructor of the class.

Comment: @user268396 I assume the OP means he wants to separately define a non-templated version, in which case such version would have it's own specialised type(s).

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure this *could* be allowed -- I suspect it was left out simply because it gained little (or nothing).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, I just overloaded each function with a version that takes new arguments, but you still need <> to instantiate the class.

Comment: @user1539179 You could use a typedef to get around that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get something close, by using default template parameters:

```
template <class T = char>
class SomeClass{};

SomeClass<> foo;     // char type
SomeClass<int> bar;  // int type
```

Use specialization if you want different behaviour for the default type's member functions.